# How to trigger a event for a list of time in android Exoplayer?

Tags: android, android-activity, media-player, exoplayer

There is a video and a paragraph of the video subtitle

I have mark each line of subtitle as an object, and each have a time with it . For example, in a paragraph like this:

```
00:00 Write a title that summarizes the specific problem

01:00 The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest. So make it count:

01:35 Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error messages, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site.

02:30 Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good impression. If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you.
```

So you can notice there is a time marked for each line.

And I would like the exoplayer trigger some event at the time, so it should trigger when play at `00:00, 01:00, 01:35, 02:30`

Here is the code to add caption

```
DataSource textDataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, bandwidthMeter, userAgent);
    SingleSampleSource textSampleSource = new SingleSampleSource(subTitleUrl, textDataSource,
          MediaFormat.createTextFormat(MediaFormat.NO_VALUE,MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP, MediaFormat.NO_VALUE, TrackRenderer.MATCH_LONGEST_US, null));
    TrackRenderer textRenderer = new TextTrackRenderer(textSampleSource, player,
          player.getMainHandler().getLooper());
```

And I have checked the document listener section:
http://devbrackets.com/dev/libs/docs/exomedia/2.4.1/index.html

but seems no resource about how to add the listener like that,

please help, thanks for helping

Comment: Hello, did you solve this issue. I have a similar problem and hoping you already solved it.